# Удалить виртуальные машины

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Так смотрю список виртуалок. Использую Virtualbox.

```
sudo vboxmanage list vms

"homestead-7" {0de19374-156b-4bac-95e0-1a92738cc13e}
"ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1541880668254_62717" {7367c136-7db8-46f8-b5d5-e2a6297dd11b}
"ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1541881130794_84895" {c4e9f606-20c2-4db9-81b7-e68074af8392}
"ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1541881264191_13644" {a2d440af-f5ab-4d6b-a3a8-e0c077fa513c}
"ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1541883924429_43127" {ecb01c3c-f7c5-4e11-be66-4e00e0090766}
"ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1541884045318_14755" {015fc91d-c3cc-4fd9-ae8a-01079f369290}
"ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1541884697036_89683" {ea006da9-a3e7-4608-a109-8e877c4482b9}
```

Как мне их удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo vboxmanage unregistervm ea006da9-a3e7-4608-a109-8e877c4482b9 --delete
```